# Java eclipse IDE line speed debug

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, optimization, eclipse-plugin

I have been working with java for a while and some programs I have made are terribly slow and parts of them run at abysmal speeds. I feel there should be a debug tool as an eclipse extension or as an existing feature that shows what lines or sections of the code are taking the longest to finish executing. Is there such a tool I could use, or is there a better way to check for optimization?

Comment: Google for `java profiler`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 for measuring before optimization!

The default `jvisualvm` and its Sampler tab can easily pinpoint the bottlenecks for you.

`jvisualvm` is on the same path as `javac`, so you just type `jvisualvm` to the console, and it runs.

On the screenshot below you can see how I'm sampling eclipse.  You can sample your own program too, just select the program on the Applications bar.

[image: jvisualvm eclipse sampling]